# Cabal tries to build unknown package when building with alex, happy in nix-shell

Tags: haskell, cabal, nix, happy, alex

I'm currently trying to build a Haskell project using nix-shell and cabal, with alex and happy as build tools. Building inside **nix-shell** (with and without `--pure`), I get the following strange error message:

```
cabal: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] trying: aoc-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: aoc:happy:exe.happy (dependency of aoc)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: aoc, aoc:happy:exe.happy)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: aoc, aoc:happy:exe.happy
```

It appears to be trying to satisfy some nonsense dependency `aoc:happy:exe.happy`, despite no reference to such a thing in the cabal file. Within the nix-shell, I am able to run `alex` and `happy` directly as executables, as they have been provided by nix.

**Question**: Does anyone know what I might be able to try to resolve this? I would like to try to provide dependencies completely using nix, instead of using `cabal update` to download packages from Hackage.

---

The source code can be found in the branch [`unhappy` here](https://github.com/chuahou/aoc/tree/unhappy), with files of interest:

- [package.yaml](https://github.com/chuahou/aoc/blob/unhappy/package.yaml) (for hpack)
- [aoc.cabal](https://github.com/chuahou/aoc/blob/unhappy/aoc.cabal)
- [default.nix](https://github.com/chuahou/aoc/blob/unhappy/default.nix)

---

Some things I've tried so far are:

- I found a similar-looking error [here](https://github.com/input-output-hk/haskell.nix/issues/798), but it was not fully resolved, and the nix build there was using **haskell.nix**.
- I've tried the following other build methods while troubleshooting:

  1. Building with cabal/ghc installed through **ghcup** (cabal 3.2.0.0, ghc 8.10.2): the build succeeds—alex and happy are fetched from Hackage and run successfully as `build-tools`.
  2. Building with **nix-build**: the build runs successfully (without packages being fetched to .cabal). `callCabal2nix` recognizes alex and happy, and provides them successfully to cabal.
  3. Building within **nix-shell** with **`cabal update`**: the same as 1. occurs and it succeeds, as nix's provided cabal fetches the packages from Hackage, but this is not what I'm trying to accomplish.
- I've also tried using nix-shell to build [a minimal example alex/happy project](https://github.com/sdiehl/write-you-a-haskell/tree/master/chapter9/happy), using the same generic *.nix files from my own project, with the same errors being produced.

Answer (score 1):

Cabal simply isn't convinced that `alex` is installed by Nixpkgs' custom Haskell environment (the `.env` attribute on the package that you correctly use for the shell).

If you run `cabal update`, cabal-install will be able to install `alex` and `happy` the way it wants and continue to build your project.

```
$ cabal v2-build
[... omitted ...]
[__0] trying: aoc-0.1.0.0 (user goal)
[__1] unknown package: aoc:happy:exe.happy (dependency of aoc)
[__1] fail (backjumping, conflict set: aoc, aoc:happy:exe.happy)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: aoc, aoc:happy:exe.happy

$ cabal update
Downloading the latest package list from hackage.haskell.org

$ cabal v2-build
Resolving dependencies...
Build profile: -w ghc-8.10.2 -O1
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - alex-3.2.6 (exe:alex) (requires download & build)
 - happy-1.20.0 (exe:happy) (requires download & build)
 - aoc-0.1.0.0 (lib) (configuration changed)
 - aoc-0.1.0.0 (exe:aoc) (dependency rebuilt)
Downloading  happy-1.20.0
[... omitted ...]
Configuring library for aoc-0.1.0.0..
Preprocessing library for aoc-0.1.0.0..
Building library for aoc-0.1.0.0..
[... omitted ...]
```

---

According to the [Cabal `build-tools` documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-build-tools) the field has been deprecated and removed. It seems like you'll be better off with [`build-tool-depends`](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-build-tool-depends).

```
    build-tool-depends:
      alex:alex >=3.2.5 && <3.3
    , happy:happy >=1.20.0 && <1.21
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried building with `build-tool-depends` instead, but the error unfortunately persists.

Comment: Seems like you didn't have a package list yet. See the answer. It's a bad error message from cabal.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I have been using nix to fulfill other dependencies so far without a package list. Running `cabal update; cabal build` does indeed work, but this makes cabal pull alex and happy from Hackage, instead of using the nix provided one. (I can tell this because it explicitly says it is downloading, and it uses 3.2.6 from Hackage instead of 3.2.5 from nix for alex).

Is there any way to get nix to properly provide alex/happy in a way that cabal recognizes, instead of using Hackage? (Your first paragraph seems to imply that there unfortunately isn't :( )

Comment: That's a solvable problem. You'd have to figure out how Cabal/cabal-install looks up build tools in the package db. With that info you could improve the package db generation in Nixpkgs. If that's not feasible, and I'd be surprised, you could even patch Cabal/cabal-install from within Nixpkgs.

Comment: Thanks for providing the direction, I'll try that out!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem? I know that the `v1-` set of commands works somewhat in these cases. However, now I am struggling with a benchmark using alex that does not work even with `v1-` commands.

Comment: For reference, there are tickets about this in the Nixpkgs issue list: https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/130556, and https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/176887.